# How to specify published package.json with library publishing in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli, publishing

Creating node modules with Angular6 should be quiet easy. The [Documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library) tells you these steps:

1. `ng generate library YOUR-LIBRARY`
2. `ng build YOUR-LIBRARY --prod`
3. `cd dist/YOUR-LIBRARY && npm publish`

This will add for instance a new project inside your `angular.json`, create a new directory inside `/projects` and compile/transpile your package into `/dist/YOUR-LIBRARY`. Thats super nice, BUT I cannot find the configuration approach to specify the exported `package.json` inside the `dist` directory.

I've tried to modify the `package.json` inside `/projects` but it does not have any effect on the distributed `package.json`.

It allways looks like:

```
{
  "name": "YOUR-LIBRARY",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0"
  },
  "main": "bundles/nls-guilloche.umd.js",
  "module": "fesm5/nls-guilloche.js",
  "es2015": "fesm2015/nls-guilloche.js",
  "esm5": "esm5/nls-guilloche.js",
  "esm2015": "esm2015/nls-guilloche.js",
  "fesm5": "fesm5/nls-guilloche.js",
  "fesm2015": "fesm2015/nls-guilloche.js",
  "typings": "nls-guilloche.d.ts",
  "metadata": "nls-guilloche.metadata.json",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

*I cannot even change the version tag or add any information. Sure, manually it would work, but this cannot be the solution, can it?*

Comment: Downvoting without any further comment is very impolite.

Comment: I am facing the same question. I would really like to be able to let the library dependencies inside the lib package.json and not having to specify them in the app's package.json. Any advances on your side regarding this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Angular 12.x each library has a `package.json` that gets generated and that file is the one that gets copied over into the output directory (`dist/` in your case).

It looks something like this when it's generated:

```
// projects/my-lib/package.json
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```